# Difference between generalized distribution functions and distribution functions

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Here are the definitions from Shiryaev's book:

> $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a distribution function if:
>
> $1)$ For $x>y$, $F(x)\geq F(y)$.
>
> $2)$ For any $y\in\mathbb{R}$: $\lim\limits_{x\downarrow y}F(x)=F(y)$ and $\lim\limits_{x\uparrow y}F(x)$ exists.
>
> $3)$ $\lim\limits_{x\downarrow -\infty}F(x)=0$ and $\lim\limits_{x\uparrow \infty}F(x)=1$.

> $G:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a generalized distribution function if:
>
> $1)$ For $x>y$, $G(x)\geq G(y)$.
>
> $2)$ For any $y\in\mathbb{R}$: $\lim\limits_{x\downarrow y}G(x)=G(y)$.
>
> $3)$ $\lim\limits_{x\downarrow -\infty}G(x)\geq0$ and $\lim\limits_{x\uparrow \infty}G(x)\leq1$.

At first I was wondering about the existence of the limit from the left for $G$ and assumed it isn't a necessary requeriment, but now I was reminded that monotone and bounded sequences converge, so I believe that $G$ has limits from the left. So now I'm confused why it is explicitly said for $F$, but not for $G$. Is my logic wrong?

Comment: You are badly mixing loose and strict inequalities. Please don't misquote books.

Comment: The existence of the left limits follows for $F$ and $G$ from the other assumptions. You noticed it for $G\,.$ In case of $F$ it's the same.